How to dissociate page numbers from the footer on latex beamer BUT keeping it
OK, so i'm having this issue using fancyhdr package: i wanted to do a decorative footer on my beamer presentation, but the page numburing doesn't go where i want  .
So i tried to do it manually by adding horizontal space \renewcommand\footrule{% \hspace{1cm}\hrulefill \raisebox{-2pt} {\quad\decofourleft\decosix\decofourright\quad}% \hrulefill \hspace{1cm}\raisebox{-2pt}{\thepage}}
but the fact is that when page numbers are increasing, it moves a little bit the decorarive bar to the left . Moreover, the page number isn't totally where i want: i want it on the lower right corner, to about 10/20 pt from the borders.
Thanks for helping!
Here's my complete code:
  \documentclass[aspectratio=43, 11pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle[python]{material}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{afterpage}


\renewcommand\footrule{%
\hspace{1cm}\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2pt}
{\quad\decofourleft\decosix\decofourright\quad}%
\hrulefill \hspace{1cm}\raisebox{-2pt}{\thepage}}





\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\title{\'Etude de l'effet Seebeck}
%\subtitle{Sous titre}
% \date{\today}
\date{}
\author{BRIENT Tidiane et MARAS Hélian}
%\institute{Center for modern beamer themes}
% \titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.pdf}}





\begin{document}

\maketitle




        \begin{frame}{Introduction}
        Problématique: Comment récupérer le maximum d’énergie perdue à cause de la chaleur dégagée par système à
l’aide de \textbf{\alert{l’effet Seebeck}} ? Comment en optimiser le rendement ?

Objectifs:
        \begin{enumerate}
        
        \item \'Etudier le \textbf{\alert{rendement}} de production de l'effet Seebeck dans le but de récupérer de \textbf{\alert{l'énergie perdue}}; \item Chercher des applications pertinentes.
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{frame}




\end{document}


Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add a complete code of what you have. Your code should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}.

Please minimise your code before posting. We really don't need dozens of frames.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz , sorry for that, i've edited the post, thx !

Don't use fancyhdr with beamer. Beamer has its own mechanism for adding footlines:
\documentclass[aspectratio=43, 11pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \quad\hrulefill\quad
  \decofourleft\decosix\decofourright
  \quad\hrulefill\quad\mbox{}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{5pt}{\insertframenumber\hspace{10pt}}}%
  \vskip4pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}


